# EditText setError message does not clear after input

Tags: android

Ok so I only have a EditText field and a button, which when pressed triggers an AsyncTask.

```
EditText playerName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.playerEditText);

if(playerName.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
    playerName.setError("Player name is required!");
else {
    // do async task
}
```

The problem is that the error message seems to stay up even after when I input valid text to search. Is there a way to remove the error as soon as the EditText is not empty?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

In your else bracket, put `playerName.setError(null)`, which will clear the error.

Comment: This will clear the error when the button is pressed, but it should be cleared when the text input changes.  It should be doing that automatically per [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence)): "The icon and error message will be reset to null when any key events cause changes to the TextView's text."

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing when pressing delete, but it clears when typing new text -- Galaxy Nexus 4.3. Haven't noticed in previous OS. So I'm gonna say Android is bugged.

Comment: Backspace seems to clear error message on my 2.3.3 phone but not on 4.1.1 with the same APK and support library

Comment: You can use a `TextWatcher` and override `afterTextChanged` method.

Comment: @blahdiblah you make a good observation. But don't think it's a bug.. Just Google's really sh*tty doco. 2nd sentence says error message will be set to "null", implying the icon is still active. The last sentence says icon and message are cleared (ie reset) only when setError(null). Google could have invested another 5 minutes writing this up.. may be too busy counting money and working on self-driving cars.

Answer (score 55):

API documentation: "The icon and error message will be reset to null when any key events cause changes to the TextView's text."
Though it is not so - and therefore we can regard this as bug.

If you use inputType such as textNoSuggestions, textEmailAddress, textPassword, the error is unset after a character is typed. Nearly as documented but again not exactly - when you delete a character, error stays.
It seems, a simple workaround with addTextChangedListener and setError(null) can attain promised behavior.

Besides there are posts about icon losing on Android 4.2. So use with care.

Comment: This answer should be ranked higher - it provides _very_ valuable information.

Comment: It's really confusing but not a bug... just pretty bad doco.... see my comment in approved answer.

Comment: 25.1.0+ still experiencing bug.

Comment: @giulio It's a bug. In my phone, for instance, the problem happens only in some `inputType` and only if I type a single char. After the second char input the `EditText` behaves as expected and the error go away. This inconsistency is more like a bug.

Answer (score 12):

Try this listener:

```
      playerName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
                {
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable edt){
                        if( playerName.getText().length()>0)
                        {
                             playerName.setError(null);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Test for length > 0 seems optional.

Comment: Its because he said "remove the error as soon as the EditText is not empty" If you don't make this test it will remove the error of empty box if the user types a char and deletes it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide the error message one way is you apply onclicklistener on the edit box and then

```
editTextName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            editTextName.setError(Null)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Uppercase fields hurt my eyes! but seriously... you should try `editTextName` instead.

Comment: This works only if the user touch the `EditTextname` precisely on its line... Less chance to happen that. (Oh that name make me vomit!!!!!)

Answer (score 3):

Below code worked for me

```
@OnTextChanged(
            value = R.id.editTextName,
            callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.TEXT_CHANGED)
    public void afterInput(CharSequence sequence) {
        editTextName.setError(null);
        editTextName.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }
```

'

> `editTextName.setError(null)` **Will clear the error message.**
>
> `editTextName.setErrorEnabled(false)` **Will remove  additional padding.**

Comment: For reading a complete explanation when using [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) go [here](http://craftedcourses.io/all-about-butter-knife-part-3/).

Answer (score 1):

Add a TextWatcher to your EditText and onError, show your error message using `et.setError(errorMessage)` else you can remove the error message and error icon like below.

```
// to remove the error message in your EditText
et.setError(null);

// to remove the error icon from EditText.
et.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver !!! I was trying for hours to remove the error icon and this saved me.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me.

textInputSetting(binding.emailEdt)

```
fun textInputSetting(view: TextInputLayout) {
    view.apply {
        this.editText!!.addTextChangedListener {
            if (this.editText!!.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                this.error = null
                this.isErrorEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are **six existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with nearly **150 votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.