# EditText with "text" inputType not hiding error popup when text is changed

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is my XML

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/barcode"
    android:id="@+id/barcode"
    android:inputType="number" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/name"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

I set error to both fields:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.barcode)).setError(getString(R.string.at_least_one_field));
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name)).setError(getString(R.string.at_least_one_field));
```

When i run the app and change content in `barcode` field it's error popup is hiding.
And when i  change content in `name` field  it's error popup is not hiding. It's hiding only when i tap on Finish button on the keyboard.

Why `number` and `text` fields have different behaviour?

Comment: In `barcode`, does it disappear after you start typing or after you've clicked in the second TextView?

Comment: @KubaSpatny it disappear when i start typing.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a "text" inputType, and found an explanation in this post **https://stackoverflow.com/a/23599214/3005955**

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable edt) {
        if( playerName.getText().length() > 0) {
            playerName.setError(null);
        }
    }
});
```