# Backspace does not clear error in EditText

Tags: android

My question is why EditText does not clear error when I press Backspace (to remove error entry).

After reviewing answers on this topic: some suggested to use TextWatcher which is clearly workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/24828706/1306324. Some stated this is an Android bug.

I decided to write the following simple test case:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text1.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView editText, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if (Integer.valueOf(text1.getText().toString())>=50) {
                        text1.setError("Must be less than 50");
                        return true; //keeps this field in focus in case I had >1 entry fields
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
       }
}
```

With layout activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And indeed I type "123" and press Done I get an error message. Then I backspace to remove 3 then 2. I still get error message. I type 2. The error message clears. This is incorrent. I think as soon as I backspace the error should clear. If this is indeed a bug then it should be fixed. I tested it with 4.1 and 4.3. Strangely it seems to work fine on my 2.3.3 though.

Answer (score 0):

When the bachspace is triggered, just set

```
text1.setError(null);
```

This will clear the error, according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html):

> If the error is null, the error message will be cleared (and you
>   should provide a null icon as well).

In your case to detect the backspace event, use the 
`keyEvent.getAction==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL` to detect the backspace.

Comment: What I am saying one should not have to do that since TextView.setError() documentation  says "The icon and error message will be reset to null when any key events cause changes to the TextView's text".

Comment: Also, softkey Backspace does not/may not invoke OnKeyListener. One has to use TextWatcher.

Comment: The documentation of the TextView is not behaving correctly whe switching through version, but here is what I found in earlier versions of the API : _Sets the right-hand compound drawable of the TextView to the "error" icon and sets an error message that will be displayed in a popup when the TextView has focus._ The documentation may have changed but the functionality hasn't.