# Android EditText : When you use android:inputType="textPersonName", the error is not removed after entering the first character

Tags: android, android-layout

When you use `android:inputType="textPersonName"` in edit text, if the error is set previously using `seterror()` method, the error is not removed after entering the first character. But if you use other `inputType` the error is removed once the first character is typed. So why the error is not removed ?

Comment: Have you tested that case on various device ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana yes i have tested in other devices. The result is same . For that particular inputType the error is not removed.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640772/edittext-seterror-message-does-not-clear-after-input

Answer (score 0):

setError(null) on your editText afterTextChanged like this

```
           edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
            {
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable edt){
                    if(edittext.getText().length()>0)
                    {
                         edittext.setError(null);
                    }
             });
```

Comment: I think we don't required to write code to hide error message manually it already taken care by OS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes ofcourse we can remove error with this code. But my question was why for that particular inputtype the error is not removed.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to set error to null. For the just 1 character input I think there might be a restriction for this input type "textPersonName". cause person cannot be just one character. I am not sure btw.